# Linux File Capabilities are lost when I modify the file. Is this expected behavior?

Tags: linux, xattr, capabilities

When I modify a file, the file capabilities I had set earlier are lost. Is this the expected behavior?

I first set a file capability:

```
$ setcap CAP_NET_RAW+ep ./test.txt
$ getcap ./test.txt
./test.txt = cap_net_raw+ep
```

As expected I found the file capability is set.

Then I modify the file.

```
$ echo hello >> ./test.txt
```

Now when I check the file capabilities, no capabilities are found.

```
$ getcap ./test.txt
```

Comment: Same question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247516/linux-file-capabilities-lost-when-i-modify-a-file-is-this-expected-behavior.  Please choose one and delete the other.

Comment: I have deleted it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is expected behaviour. I don't have a document that says it but you can see in [this patch](https://lwn.net/Articles/244747/) from 2007

> When a file with posix capabilities is overwritten, the
>       file capabilities, like a setuid bit, should be removed.
>
> This patch introduces security_inode_killpriv().  This is
>       currently only defined for capability, and is called when
>       an inode is changed to inform the security module that
>       it may want to clear out any privilege attached to that inode.
>       The capability module checks whether any file capabilities
>       are defined for the inode, and, if so, clears them.

`security_inode_killpriv` is still in the kernel today, being called from 
[`notify_change`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/attr.c#n274)
when an inode is changed in "response to write or truncate":
see [`dentry_needs_remove_privs`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/inode.c#n1797)

```
 /* Return mask of changes for notify_change() that need to be done as a
  * response to write or truncate... */
 int dentry_needs_remove_privs(struct dentry *dentry)
```

Comment: This also happens when a `chown` call is done. Even if the user and group does not change, since it change the inode.